# Simple Jquery slider wont load picture with .show

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

I followed a tutorial to a tee but i just cant get it to work, it loads the loading gif and hides the other images but this .show function doesnt do anything, am i missing something?

```
<style type="text/css">
.slider{
width:800px;
height:350px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:30px auto;
background-image:url(img/load.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
}
.shadow{
background-image:url(img/shadow.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:top;
width:864px;
height:144px;
margin:-60px auto;
}
.slider img{
width:800px;
height:350px;
display:none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function Slider(){
    $(".slider #1").show("fade",500);
}

</script>
</head>

 <body onload="Slider();">
<div class="slider">
    <img id="1" src="img/image1.jpg" border="0" alt="Image 1"/>
    <img id="2" src="img/image2.jpg" border="0" alt="Image 2"/>
    <img id="3" src="img/image3.jpg" border="0" alt="Image 3"/>
</div>
<div class="shadow">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: AFAIK a id-attribute cant just be a number (or start with a number), perhaps this was changed in html5.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$(".slider #1").show("fade",500);` with 
`$(".slider #1").fadeIn(500);`

http://jsfiddle.net/Ty7ce/

Comment: Is this new or has this always been the way to do it? i know that the tutorial was during UI 1.8.18 where do you learn how to correctly implement this? because now im meant to have it .hide("slide",) left or whatever

Comment: It's has been always the way to do it. You can use `$(".slider #1").show(500);` as well. Check out jQuery documentation. http://api.jquery.com/show/